# CKEditor not returning value in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, ckeditor

### CKEditor not returning value in IE7

Hope someone can help. I have integrated CKEditor into a site and everything works fine except for in IE7.

I've integrated CKEditor by adding `<TEXTAREA>` tabs in my HTML and giving them the class `ckeditor`. CKEditor then "converts" these into CKEditor instances when the page loads instead of standard `TEXTAREA` controls.

I am then retrieving the value using `Request.Form["ControID"]` in my server side code (C#). For most browsers this works fine but in IE7 no value is returned despite the control containing text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this problem I have resolved it by reverting to version 4.1.3 of CKeditor which is apparently the latest version to support IE7.

Alternatively you can also copy the contents of the CKEditor instance out to a hidden control prior to form submission:

```
$('#hdnHiddenControl').val(CKEDITOR.instances.txtCKEditorControl.getData());
```